# Python code in Zapier (invalid syntax (usercode.py, line 42))

Tags: python

This code is pre-made in a Zapier forum to pull failed responses from another piece of software called iAuditor. When I plug in the code and update the API token and webhook URL this error pops up:

Traceback (most recent call last):
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (usercode.py, line 42)

Here is the code:

```
[code]

import json
import requests

auth_header = {'Authorization': 'a4fca847d3f203bd7306ef5d1857ba67a2b3d66aa455e06fac0ad0be87b9d226'}
webhook_url = 'https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/3950922/efka9n/'
api_url = 'https://api.safetyculture.io/audits/'
audit_id = input['audit_id']
audit_doc = requests.get(api_url + audit_id, headers=auth_header).json()
failed_items = []
audit_author = audit_doc['audit_data']['authorship']['author']
conducted_on = audit_doc['audit_data']['date_completed']
conducted_on = conducted_on[:conducted_on.index('T')]
audit_title = audit_doc['template_data']['metadata']['name']
for item in audit_doc['items']:
    if item.get('responses') and item['responses'].get('failed') == True:
        label = item.get('label')
        if label is None:
            label = 'no_label'
        responses = item['responses']
        response_label = responses['selected'][0]['label']
        notes = responses.get('text')
        if notes is None:
            notes = ''
        failed_items.append({'label': label,
            'response_label': response_label,
            'conducted_on': conducted_on,
            'notes': notes,
            'author': audit_author
        })
for item in failed_items:
    r = requests.post(webhook_url, data = item)
    return response.json()
[/code]
```

Comment: Your code has length 32 lines and the error appears in line 42....

Comment: Yes I noticed that. Any idea what would cause that to happen?

Comment: Maybe you copied a different file than actually the one with the error?

Comment: No, this is the only piece of python code I have ever dealt with. This error is coming from this code.

Comment: I removed the [code] and [/code] and now am getting this error:       Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmpLu46ym/usercode.py", line 16, in the_function
    audit_author = audit_doc['audit_data']['authorship']['author']
KeyError: 'audit_data'

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an error from the platform. It looks like Zapier uses a script called `usercode.py` to bootstrap launching your script and the error seems to be coming from that part.